# How to change already assigned route in ASP.NET web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please point me to right question if this is a duplicate. I haven't quite found one that addresses what I expressing.

So I have a controller that has two same routes

```
// GET: api/UserPwordHints/5
[ResponseType(typeof(UserPwordHintsModels))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserPwordHintsModels(string id)

// PUT: api/UserPwordHints/5
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutUserPwordHintsModels(string id, 
UserPwordHintsModels userPwordHintsModels)
```

The only difference is the HTTP Method. Now when I use the route, the second route is called

```
  // PUT: api/UserPwordHints/5
```

My WebConfig.cs looks like this

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Which is the default. I know through my search on SO that I have add a code that explicitly directs which one to use. However they both have the same route. What would be best way to tell which exact one to use?

EDIT: Using a GET Method still calls the PUT Method with an Error

```
cannot send a content-body with this verb-type post
```

EDIT2 Calling Method

```
GET_METHOD = "GET"
SendWebRequest(getPassWordHintURL, requestBody:=body, httpMethod:=GET_METHOD)


Private Function SendWebRequest(
                   requestUrl As String,
                   Optional requestBody As String = Nothing,
                   Optional httpMethod As String = "POST",
                   Optional bearerToken As String = Nothing) As String

        Dim responseFromServer

        httpReq = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl)
        httpReq.Proxy = Nothing
        httpReq.Method = httpMethod
        httpReq.ContentType = "application/json"

        If bearerToken IsNot Nothing Then
            httpReq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + bearerToken)
        End If

        httpReq.ContentLength = 0

        If requestBody IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody)
            httpReq.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length
            Dim stream = httpReq.GetRequestStream()
            stream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length)
            stream.Close()
        End If

        Dim resp As WebResponse
        Try
            resp = httpReq.GetResponse()
            Dim dataStream = resp.GetResponseStream()
            Dim reader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
            ' Read the content.
            responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd()

            dataStream.Close()
        Catch ex As WebException
            Throw ex
        End Try

        Return responseFromServer
    End Function
```

Comment: What value is coming in `httpMethod`?

Comment: The value "GET"

Comment: you are setting http method ="POST" in you VB code, You need to change it to "Get" or "Put" for calling different API's Method, Before calling the API from code you need to test it by calling API through some tools like Postman etc

Comment: @AnsBilal Its an Optional Variable so it only sets to POST if no HttpMethod is passed in. I have changed it to GET to test and it changes to whatever httpmethod you pass in . I will try using some tools since its behaving weird

Comment: Yeah first test you API using some tool, I will recommend https://www.getpostman.com/ . So that you will make it clear that either problem is in your API or in your Calling code

Comment: @AnsBilal Weird thing is Postman is hitting the API with GET but my code is not. I notice that when I send my required with "POST" , it get passed in as a string "POST" with orange color in my debugger indicating a string. But when I send my request using "GET" , it gets passed as string but the color of the variable in my debugger is grayed out. Weird

Comment: Debugging is the key of success. I can't help you any more.

Answer (score 0):

Routes defined for both the methods are same, but *type of method is different*
No need to change default route.

If you want to call `GetUserPwordHintsModels()`, then use route as

```
   // GET: api/UserPwordHints/5
       ^^^^ See the difference
```

If you want to call `PutUserPwordHintsModels()`, then use route as

```
 // PUT: api/UserPwordHints/5
    ^^^^ PUT and GET
```

You can decorate your methods using `HTTPPut` and `HTTPGet` annotations. Similar to

```
// GET: api/UserPwordHints/5
[ResponseType(typeof(UserPwordHintsModels)), HTTPGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserPwordHintsModels(string id)

// PUT: api/UserPwordHints/5
[ResponseType(typeof(void)), HTTPPut]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutUserPwordHintsModels(string id, 
UserPwordHintsModels userPwordHintsModels)
```

For more details : [MSDN Routing to controller actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Even when I use the GET Method, it still tries to call the PUT Method so I get an error (cannot send a content-body with this verb-type post) basically telling me the route is expecting a different method than I am using

Comment: Thanks for the help. Its still not using the Get route even after Annotating the methods. Running into same error

Comment: From where you are calling API, can you provide that code. I believe you need to change your calls there as well. It is unlikely that after `GET` and `PUT` annotations api calls will redirect to the same API.
Even if it redirects to the same API, then you can distinguish it by passing extra parameter in the URL **i.e. userPwordHintsModels**  this will definitely redirect to PUT method

Comment: Looks like you are right about something being wrong with the calling method after the annotations. Now when I provide the PUT or GET method, I run into the error. When I remove the annotations, the method calls the PUT route with a PUT Method specified.

Comment: The error is cannot send a content-body with this verb-type post.

Comment: Can you update your question with calling method for this API